# How to not display password inside v-uiId and rpc vaadin 7

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

How do I not display the password inside the v-uiId in rpc, using vaadin 7.7.14.

My password field looks like this:

```
PasswordField senha = new PasswordField("Senha");
```

And how is it inside the v-uiId rpc:

`[ [ "126", "v", "v", [ "text", [ "s", "lucascoelho" ] ] ], [ "126", "v", "v", [ "c", [ "i", 11 ] ] ], [ "127", "v", "v", [ "text", [ "s", "senha.123" ] ] ], [ "127", "v", "v", [ "c", [ "i", 9 ] ] ], [ "127", "v", "v", [ "blur", [ "s", "" ] ] ] ]`

Password obfuscated or removed from rpc.

my user is "lucascoelho" and password is "password.123"

Comment: You should use https so that third parties can't view the network traffick.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in `Password` component always uses the value as it has been set. Normally this is totally safe, as all communication between server and client are in encrypted SSL pipe.

You can simply not set the password as a field value if you don't want it to be a field value. (i.e. do not call setValue method)

However if this is still problem for you, there is [one way version of the PasswordField](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/onewaypasswordfield-add-on) available in the Vaadin's Directory.

Comment: How would this be done?